# Why this pointer pass a value not address in calculating sum?

Tags: c++

I am confused about the pointer when passing to functions in C++, when put *arr in the parameter(line 3), is it means `int *arr = balance` , I know balance can refer the first element address in the array, but the problem is why arr[i] refers the first element value?
I think *arr means value, while arr means address...

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
double getAverage(int *arr, int size);
int main(){
    int balance[5] = {1000, 2, 3, 17, 50};
    double avg;
    avg = getAverage(balance, 5);
    cout << avg << endl;
    return 0;
}

double getAverage(int *arr, int size){
    int i, sum = 0;
    double avg;
    for (i = 0; i< size; i++){
        sum += arr[i];  //in this line, I think it should sum += *arr[i], arr means a address, isn't?
    }
    avg = double(sum) / size;
    return avg;
}
```

Comment: Are you asking why you write `arr[i]` and not `*arr[i]` when accessing an array element? For pointers, `arr[i]` is just syntax sugar for `*(arr + i)`. Writing `*arr[i]` would be equivalent to `*(*(arr + i))`, which is clearly not what you want.

Comment: Programming with (dynamic) arrays in C++ becomes much easier with std::vector.

Comment: Example here : https://godbolt.org/z/1saYe5G1T

Comment: @Brian Thanks a lot, I got your idea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An array identifier cast to a pointer when used with brackets `[]` or when dereferencing with `*`, so in main `balance` is treated as a pointer when not using brackets.

When the brackets are placed after a pointer, they will add an offset to the pointer, based on the size of the object type in memory, then dereference the pointer.  Using the `*` directly on a pointer dereferences the pointer without applying an offset.

So basically `*balance` and `balance[0]` will both return the first element in the array.

In C the array is not passed as an object as a function parameter, but rather as a pointer to the first object in the array, which is why the parameter type is `int *` and you are passing to the function `balance`, which is a cast to a pointer that points to the first element in the array.  Note `balance` would also behave the same as`&(balance[0])` when used in this context.

Comment: `balance` is not exactly equivalent to `&(balance[0])`. It depends on the context whether `balance` does decay to a pointer or not: https://godbolt.org/z/6schssh51

Comment: To help avoid confusion down the line, it's worth emphasizing that arrays themselves are not pointers and will behave very differently from pointers in some contexts. Arrays are effectively pointers only in the sense that C++ will implicitly convert an array to a pointer. This happens in the [exact same way](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion) as, for instance, a `char` being promoted to `int`.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number Good point.  It would not behave the same in all contexts.  Revised to state that this would apply when used as a pointer.

Comment: @Brian - Thanks for the feedback.  Made the correction.